# What constitutes a day on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, timezone, time

What constitutes a period that spans a *day* on Stack Overflow? I was awarded reputation points at ca. 21:00 last evening and then again this morning at ca. 10:00 and yet the "Recent Achievements" dropdown lists both as having been awarded *Today*.

This is purely out of curiosity, but are comments/questions/flags recorded similarly or is this method reserved solely for recording how long ago a point has been awarded? Wouldn't *last 24 hours* be more accurate?

Is there a predetermined time after which rep points are logged as being earned on the following day?

Comment: 20:00 Eastern is when *today* begins.

Comment: @Compass Note that daylight savings makes that statement false for half of the year.

Comment: @Servy: Assuming that's US Eastern time, it's *never* correct. It would be 19:00 (winter) or 20:00 (summer) as EST is UTC-5 and EDT is UTC-4.

Comment: I suck at doing math, but with this edit, I'll die knowing I was right about half the time.

Comment: On Meta, it's when a user rages and repeatedly insults us. Or at least, that's when I call it a day.

Comment: @Bart So *that's* why you spend so little time on Meta.

Comment: @Bart If that's the start of a day, I would hate to think what the *end* is like.

Comment: Hover over an entry like "10 secs ago" and you know what time it was 10 seconds ago.

Comment: Note that you can see the current UTC time by looking in the very top right corner of the "Recent Achievements" dropdown.

Comment: "Duplicate" of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-time-zone-do-sos-servers-operate-in

Answer (score 81, accepted):

SE is on UTC time.  00:00 UTC is the start of the next day.

Comment: Click your achievement dropdown to see the current UTC time in 24-hour format. Alternatively, go to http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/ to see UTC in your local time.

Comment: Or [click here](https://www.google.com/search?q=00:00+UTC+to+local) (if Google can correctly determine your timezone, at least)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi That's a *weird* place for a clock, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: I took the liberty to put it in an answer since it might be useful to a lot of people.

Comment: ARGH... "UTC time"... I bet you enter PIN numbers in your ATM machine, don't you and then watch sports on the ESPN network.

Answer (score 23):

We use UTC here on all SE sites, so a 'day' is a day according to the UTC time zone. You can easily see the current UTC time in your Achievements:

[image]