# Went on StackExchange app did not read consecutive days!

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I went on the app today but yet it did not read my consecutive day and yet it did not update/read that I was on the website today, and I really do wish it was based on current location of time, because it's still Saturday were I am.

Will it ever be switched to read the user location so at least if I ever run into the issue before I sleep I can make sure it read the consecutive days?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/make-recent-activity-today-etc-buttons-based-on-users-time-zone

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278816/what-constitutes-a-day-on-stack-overflow